# Mead: is it time to bottling?

Tags: fermentation, bottling, first-time-brewer, mead

I have a few questions. I'm making mead for the first time. My mead is now brewing for 2 months (since 11th august), but I'm not sure if it's time to bottle it. That's because it is still sparking. I know that it is the consequence of the brewing, but since the sparkle is not that strong as it was at the beginning, in fact it is very weak.

1- Can I bottle it or I have to wait until the mead is completely still?

2- Also, when I shake it, bubbles of CO2 are still coming up from the airlock. What should I do?

3- And what kind of caps should I use (sugar cap, plastic, metal crown stoppers, ...)?

You can also see from the pic the mead is still turbid, I guess.
Thanks for your help!

P.S.: I've used brewer's yeast.[image]!

Comment: The only way to know for sure would be to check the gravity readings.  If they are inline with what the recipe shows, then bottle it.  However, mead usually takes a lot longer then 3 months.

Comment: Oh okay thank you! By the way, should I transfer the mead in a new container in order to left the "dead" yeast in the previous jar? Or it's not a necessary step?

Comment: It is a good thing to do if you plan on letting the mead in the container for several months, other than that, it's not required.

Comment: Yes, it's always a good idea to rack off the yeast. Oh, and stop shaking it! :-)

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, I do not trust that handle in the slightest. Would not recommend using it unless the carboy is empty

Answer (score 2):

1- Two months is a bit soon to bottle. Wait until the mead is still else you will wind up with bottle bombs due to the continued fermentation. The only real way to know for sure is to use your hydrometer from beginning to end. Best practices include adding Potassium Sorbate and Campden tablets to ensure fermentation doesn't continue once in the bottle.

2- Stop shaking your mead! You continue to see CO2 bubbles rise because it isn't done fermenting and my guess is it should probably be de-gassed thoroughly. De-gassing is the process of removing suspended carbon dioxide left over from fermentation.Suspended carbon dioxide prevents wine from properly clearing. Carbon dioxide can be removed from mead through three main methods: agitation, creating a vacuum, and time. 
Agitation is usually done with a type of stirring rod that attaches to a power drill. 
A vacuum can be created by sealing off the top of your carboy and removing the air that is in there.When there’s negative pressure in the carboy the carbon dioxide will come out of suspension (form bubbles) and float to the top of the carboy.
The easiest way to degas a mead is through time. Given enough time all the carbon dioxide will come out of suspension and leave your mead.
If you choose this method be sure that you’re not storing your mead on the lees. Rack off of all sediment and let the CO2 escape slowly. Should more sediment accumulate you’ll have to consider racking again to avoid off flavors from the decomposing yeast.

3- Caps will depend on the bottles you use. Metal beer style caps seem to work best for me.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I've already racked it in a new jug and now I'm waiting for the mead to clear up. I'm just worried that I may have left too much of empty space in the jug. So you advise me to open it regularly so as to de-gas it? But the exposure to the air may not cause the mead to turn into vinegar? I'm not that sure, just asking, but this the fact which concerns me the most. In the end, sadly I don't have an hydrometer since this is my first time brewing and I didn't know that I needed this stuff. But I'm surely going to pick it for the next time.